# Multiple match conditions for same array element

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection named "devices" with roughly 50,000 documents. I'm trying to query the "routes" array within each document and have it return the document if multiple conditions are met for the individual array elements. The problem is it seems Mongo is giving back answers where the multiple conditions are satisfied for different array elements.

Sample Data:

```
{
    "_id": 0,
    "name": "example1",
    "serial": "123456",
    "routes": [
        {
            "description": "8989",
            "zone": "front"
        },
        {
            "description": "1221",
            "zone": "back"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "example2",
    "serial": "987654",
    "routes": [
        {
            "description": "1515",
            "zone": "front"
        },
        {
            "description": "8989",
            "zone": "side"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried simple .find() variations with no luck including

```
db.devices.find({"routes.description":"8989", "routes.zone":"front"})
db.devices.find({"$and": [{"routes.description":"8989"}, {"routes.zone":"front"}]})
```

I've also tried aggregations which seems to fail on me since my understanding of them is elementary. The desired results for the queries above would be a single document ("_id":0) and not both documents.

```
{ "_id" : 0, "name" : "example1", "serial" : "123456", "routes" : [ { "description" : "8989", "zone" : "front" }, { "description" : "1221", "zone" : "back" } ] }
```

Additionally, the ability to query the array using the $in operator would be desired. For example, the following query's desired output would be both documents since both of them have routes that match "zone":"front" and "descriptions" that are in the list.

```
db.devices.find({"$and": [{"routes.description": { $in: ["8989", "1515"] }}, {"routes.zone":"front"}]})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply need to use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) here

```
db.devices.find({routes: {$elemMatch: {description:"8989", zone:"front"}}})
```

[Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vLfy0MpCVjo)

Comment: can you answer this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67600862/convert-mongo-query-to-spring-data-query